# HTML5 Game Develop - Mobile Movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'v made this game:
http://yonicks.com/HTML5_Game/game.html

it was made firstly for web not mobile.

I'm trying to add to it events that when I tilt my phone the octopus will move to that side.

its currently working good on android phones, it just need to move when I tilt it. (need it only for android's phone for now)

Can anyone help me? need to send it until 00:00 today

**update:** working now on android.

**one more question, I don't know why but the game isn't running on IOS devices, i think it's because of part where I use ajax to get the game data from XML, how i can fix it ? ( dunno even how to debug it)
on IOS device I can see only the "enter your name" box, without the canvas box.**

update: i Found the problem in IOS, this code aint working:

```
var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';
imgSprite.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

can anyone tell me why? and what i can do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/devicemotion) event works on iOS and some newer Android versions.

Comment: thnaks! worked great, what about older androids ?

Comment: As far as I know most smartphones from the last couple of years should support this.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the onload event doesn't fire for images.  You can try downloading the image using an ajax request and assigning it to an image object instead.